# Setting springfox.documentation.enabled=false doesn't disable swagger 3.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I tried to disable Swagger 3.0 in production. Some people posted a solution: add `springfox.documentation.enabled=false` to application-prod.properties, but it doesn't work in my Spring Boot application.

I use Spring Initializr to select Spring Boot 2.7.1, Maven, Java 8, spring-boot-starter-web, and spring-boot-starter-actuator. Then I add dependency below to my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
```